# For Loop in Decendents (Sequence contains no Element ) c#

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xml-parsing

I have a complex XML file where I want to retrieve values from specific transaction tag.At the end, i need to take the values to a CSV file.

[image: Please see the xml file format]

I am trying to retrieve the value of below in each transaction tags where it is present.

```
<szCustomerID>2988880562567</szCustomerID>

   <szCustomerName>130808125028SHM </szCustomerName>

   <szExternalID>3177@06/07/17</szExternalID>
```

Note that all transaction tag is not the same
Unfortunately it is looping through all transaction tags and i am getting error sequence contains no element

Is there a way i can loop withing the Descendants and always skip the second transaction tag since i won't be needing it

```
  try
        {
            string strSource_voucher = @"C:\\TempFid";

                  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(strSource_voucher, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            if (files.Length > 0) // Check if files has values
            {
                StringBuilder dataToBeWritten = new StringBuilder();


                foreach (string file in files)
                {

                    dataToBeWritten.Append("szCustomerID");
                    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");
                    dataToBeWritten.Append("szCustomerName");
                    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");
                    dataToBeWritten.Append("szExternalID");
                    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

                    dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);

                    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(file);


                    int results = xDocument.Descendants("Transaction").Count();

                    foreach (var trans in xDocument.Descendants("Transaction"))

                    {
                           //var trans = xDocument.Descendants("Transaction");

                           var val1 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szCustomerID").First();

                            var val2 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szCustomerName").First();


                            var val3 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szExternalID").First();

                            dataToBeWritten.Append(val1);
                            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

                            dataToBeWritten.Append(val2);
                            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

                            dataToBeWritten.Append(val3);
                            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

                            dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);


                    } // End of For each var trans


                    Console.WriteLine(dataToBeWritten.ToString());

                    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `for` loop and increase`i` by 2 like this:

```
var transactions = xDocument.Descendants("Transaction").ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < transactions.Count(); i += 2)
{

    //var trans = xDocument.Descendants("Transaction");
    var val1 = (string)transactions[i].Descendants("Set").Elements("szCustomerID").First();
    var val2 = (string)transactions[i].Descendants("Set").Elements("szCustomerName").First();
    var val3 = (string)transactions.Descendants("Set").Elements("szExternalID").First();

    dataToBeWritten.Append(val1);
    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

    dataToBeWritten.Append(val2);
    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

    dataToBeWritten.Append(val3);
    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

    dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);
} // End of For each var trans
```

Comment: Is there a way i can seperate the content of the szExternalID in the csv file?example i need 3177 and 06/07/17 in seperate column ?

Comment: @LBoodia if you split val3 by '@' you will get back array containing 3177 as first element and 06/07/17 as second element, then you just need to write them seperate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Element` instead of `Elements` and check if the value is not `null`

```
foreach (var trans in xDocument.Descendants("Transaction"))
{
    XElement setElement = trans.Descendants("Set").FirstOrDefault();
    if (setElement != null)
    {
        var val1 = (string)setElement.Element("szCustomerID");
        var val2 = (string)setElement.Element("szCustomerName");
        var val3 = (string)setElement.Element("szExternalID");

        if (val1 != null && val3 != null && val3 != null)
        {
            dataToBeWritten.Append(val1);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

            dataToBeWritten.Append(val2);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

            dataToBeWritten.Append(val3);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

            dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He has `Set` element with some other elements in it in every `Transaction`. I think this If will always return `true`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Nothing in this code returns `true`. It will return the element if exists or `null` if it doesn't exists.

Comment: `if (setElement != null)` this will be always `true`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov OK I understand what you mean. In the xml the OP provided there is `Set` tag in every `Transaction`, however the OP did say there is a different structure for some of them. If the `Set` is missing somewhere without the check he will get an exception.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But your code is checking if `Set` has at least one `Descendant`, right? But in his example `Set` always has `Descendants`, and the problem is that when `Set` has not `szCustomerID` and `szCustomerName` the Transaction must be skipped.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov There are two checks, for `Set` in `setElement != null` and for the values in `if (val1 != null && val3 != null && val3 != null)`. `setElement.Element` will return the node if found or `null`.

Comment: I understand that. But why get values and then check if they are `null` or not if the OP says that the problematic `Transactions` is the every second one.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov For this specific scenario you can do as the accepted answer suggested. IMO more generic solution is preferable so I posted one.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this type of conversion, if you are open to use  library ([Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - An open source ETL lib)

Stream based, fast to convert any xml to csv format with few lines of codes.

I believe you want to product CSV file from your xml having CUSTOMER table elements only.

Here is how you can do with this library

```
using (var parser = new ChoXmlReader("sample.xml").WithXPath("/UpdateDB/Transaction")
    .WithField("Table", xPath: "/Insert/Table")
    .WithField("szCustomerID", xPath: "/Insert/Set/szCustomerID")
    .WithField("szCustomerName", xPath: "/Insert/Set/szCustomerName")
    .WithField("szExternalID", xPath: "/Insert/Set/szExternalID")
    )
{
    using (var writer = new ChoCSVWriter("sample.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
        writer.Write(parser.Where(r => r.Table == "CUSTOMER").Select(r => new { szCustomerID = r.szCustomerID, szCustomerName = r.szCustomerName, szExternalID = r.szExternalID }));
}
```

The output will look as below

```
szCustomerID,szCustomerName,szExternalID
2988880562567,130808125028SHM,3177@06/07/17
12345,130808125028SHM,3177@06/07/17
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to split the szExternalID into 2 columns (szExternalID, szExternalDate), you will have to use the valueconverter to parse and load them. Sample shows how

```
using (var parser = new ChoXmlReader("sample.xml").WithXPath("/UpdateDB/Transaction")
    .WithField("Table", xPath: "/Insert/Table")
    .WithField("szCustomerID", xPath: "/Insert/Set/szCustomerID")
    .WithField("szCustomerName", xPath: "/Insert/Set/szCustomerName")
    .WithField("szExternalID", xPath: "/Insert/Set/szExternalID", valueConverter: (v) => ((string)v).Split('@')[0])
    .WithField("szExternalDate", xPath: "/Insert/Set/szExternalID", valueConverter: (v) => ((string)v).Split('@')[1])
    )
{
    using (var writer = new ChoCSVWriter("sample.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
        writer.Write(parser.Where(r => r.Table == "CUSTOMER").Select(r => new { szCustomerID = r.szCustomerID, szCustomerName = r.szCustomerName, szExternalID = r.szExternalID, szExternalDate = r.szExternalDate }));
}
```

The new output will look as below

```
szCustomerID,szCustomerName,szExternalID,szExternalDate
2988880562567,130808125028SHM,3177,06/07/17
12345,130808125028SHM,3177,06/07/17
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: is there a way i can seperate the content of the szExternalID in the csv file?example i need 3177 and 06/07/17 in seperate column